# How to print number with commas as thousands separator and decimal places in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, number-formatting

I'm trying to display numbers in my Django templates with

1. commas as thousand sepaerator and
2. specifying the decimal places to round to.

e.g. 76384.8739439 -> 76,384.87

Django has template tags to achieve both these.

- intcomma - for thousand separator and
- floatformat - for decimal places

I can't seem to find a way to do both at the same time without writing my own custom template filter. Anybody know of an easier solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
{{ value|floatformat:2|intcomma }}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks @Dogbert. I tried {{ value|intcomma|floatformat:2 }} but it didn't work and then didn't think of swapping the filters around?!

Comment: It do not work when using L10N + a different deciaml and thousands separators...   9999.99 becomes 9,999,99